# Change TableView Size programmatically in code

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to change the whole Table View Size (x, y, width, height) in the code and not in the Main StoryBoard. 
I made the table view in the story board without layouts.
I tried this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width
        tableView.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height
        tableView.reloadData()
}
```

But It didn't work

Comment: do in viewwillappear/viewdidappear instead of view did load

Comment: also, what is the initial size of table view ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in `viewDidAppear`:

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
```

Comment: Did you added constraints to the tableView in the storyboard?

Answer (score 2):

`CGRect` is a struct, meaning that every time you access the `frame` property you obtain a copy of the rectangle. Changing fields in the rectangle affects only the local copy, and not the value used by the view.

So in order to update any fields of the `frame` property, you need to set it all at once:

```
var frame = tableView.frame
frame.size.width = ...
frame.size.height = ...
tableView.frame = frame
```

Assuming there are no other things that affect the frames of your views (autolayout constraints, autoresizing masks), this will update the frame to the new value.

Also please note that the `viewDidLoad` might not be the best place to set frames, as those properties might not be yet initialised. `viewWillAppear` is a better place for example.

Comment: I tried this now: 
`var frame = tableView.frame;
        frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
        frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height;
        tableView.frame = frame; `
And it didn't work..

Comment: Is `self.view.frame` having the expected value?